# what is outer div in css?

Tags: html, css

what is outer div? whats the use? give me one

Answer (score 2):

An outer div is a div that wraps some other HTML elements. Like this:

```
<div>
    <label for="foo">Foo</label>
    <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" />
</div>
```

Comment: i cant get it...can you tell me briefly?

Comment: In my example the `<div>` tag contains the `<label>` and `<input>` HTML elements inside.

Comment: @jagan please start putting some more effort into your questions. Be more verbose, provide more context. Otherwise, your future on SO will be a very short-lived one

Answer (score 0):

Outer Div is a `<DIV>` which surrounds your actual html control.